# Matter test with Google Nest Hub 2nd

Tags: google-smart-home, matter-iot-standard

I am testing Google Nest Hub 2nd Gen and Wi-Fi only Matter device.
My Android phone and Google Nest Hub 2nd Gen are connected.
However, the Google Home App doesn't find the Wi-Fi only Matter device.
Does Google Nest Hub 2nd Gen support matter over Wi-Fi?

Do I need to have a Google developer account?

Answer (score 0):

- Nest 2nd Gen Hub are able to work with Matter over Wi-Fi devices. Sounds like you are having trouble commissioning your device to a Google Account . You can take a look at the following [doc](https://developers.home.google.com/matter/primer/commissioning) for getting ideas with commissioning. For the errors you are getting on the GHA during commissioning you can take a look at the [troubleshooting guide](https://developers.home.google.com/matter/troubleshooting#pairing) to see if any of the solutions solve your issue.
- Matter is currently public and you don’t need a developer account to use it, any account should work fine. If  you are a developer you can follow the get started guide for developing your wifi only matter devices. If you are an end user please reach out to the company developing the device  to refer to Google’s documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Your device (like matter enabled light bulbs) should connect out-of-box, without any configuration. If you can't see any matter option in your google home app or in settings->google->devices & sharing, you don't have required google play services. Try updating your google play services.

If it is your own device that you're trying to commission on matter network with nest hub 2, you will have to register that device in google matter developer console (note that vendor and product IDs - PID and VID in device setup in google device console should match the ones on your device).